# MS Access OpenForm was cancelled - error 2501

Tags: database, vba, ms-access-2010

I've been asked to make some modification to Forms in an Access database used by a group I work with.  I had to add a data entry form similar to one that exists so I copied one of the existing forms and made some modifications.  When I click the button to open the form to test it I get this error:

Run-time error '2501'
The OpenForm action was cancelled.

Here is the code that is called to cause this error:

```
Private Sub cmdCPE_EntryForm_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdCPE_EntryForm_Click

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    stDocName = "CPE_EntryForm"
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName ', , , stLinkCriteria

Exit_cmdCPE_EntryForm_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdCPE_EntryForm_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdCPE_EntryForm_Click

End Sub
```

Thx in advance for any assitance.

Comment: It feels like something got screwed up when the form was copied. If I link the button to a new form it works and opens it fine.

Comment: Problem is I've done a lot of formatting on this form so to do it all again would kind of suck.  If this can be resolved that would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when my form was referring to a query that no longer existed.
Once I updated the form to point to an existing query, my code worked fine.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. I have a universal form for adding a "type", which I program with a public function, and call from not in list events for drop down controls. When I brought this universal form into a new application, it had been saved with a row source that didn't exist in this new app. It was cancelling the open when it tried to load. I cleared out the row source, and now it works! Well done.

Answer (score 2):

the form you're trying to open is in design view. Close design view

Answer (score 2):

My form open error 2501 "Form Open Cancelled" error in MSAccess was due to the form's data source table not existing.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime Error 2501 can occur on calling the OpenForm method if there is a problem with the database.

Try following the steps in this link under the headings "Recovering from corruption" and "Symptom: Cannot open a form or report"?

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html

Could also be a problem with the new form's Open or Load events, might be worth posting that code as well for review.

Comment: My bet is on Form_Open.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error when I wanted to open a form containing a sub form whose data was located in another folder. By decreasing the path of the dorsal base this has repaired the error. For example, the first path was `C:\Dev\Application\Vers1\Prog\Debug\myAppDB.accdb`, so I decreased the path's length in : `C:\Dev\Debug\myAppDB.accdb` and this solved the problem. The same error occurred with a network path, and I fixed it with the same method.

By assuming that you have :
a command button named "cmdOpenForm" and
a form called: "myForm"

I have also add this code on the On Click Event of the command button :

```
Private Sub cmdOpenForm_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdOpenForm_Click
    If CurrentProject.AllForms("myForm").IsLoaded = True Then
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "myForm"
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenForm "myForm", acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal, Me.Form.Name
    End If
Exit_cmdOpenForm_Click:
Exit Sub
Err_cmdOpenForm_Click:
MsgBox "Error number : " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Error: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
Resume Exit_cmdOpenForm_Click
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your RecordScorce is not recognized. Type your recordScource In Code, then in Menu Tool\Reference Change place of your references.Then Debug your project And then save it.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the forms that you want to open then rerun the code. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact error when opening a form after making a small change to some VBA code on a sub-form. Doing a "Compact and Repair" on the database fixed it.